# Filter by value or show all if no value

Tags: sql-server, functions

I have 2 tables: **records** and **access_rights**

Access table has list of permission for certain and should be used to filter records based on rules:

- function field is mandatory
- object field is optional. if it`s empty do not apply filter else filter by value
  All rules should work in one query. Please see example of expected output and SQL Fiddle data.

  ```
  | ID |   FUNCTION |   OBJECT | SUM |
  |----|------------|----------|-----|
  |  1 | Function 1 | Object 1 | 900 |
  |  4 | Function 1 | Object 2 | 750 |
  |  5 | Function 2 | Object 2 | 200 |
  ```

Thanks in advance!

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91496/7)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE records (
  [id] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [function] varchar(100),
  [object] varchar(100),
  [sum] money
  );

INSERT INTO records VALUES
(1, 'Function 1', 'Object 1', 900),
(2, 'Function 2', 'Object 1', 600),
(3, 'Function 3', 'Object 1', 800),
(4, 'Function 1', 'Object 2', 750),
(5, 'Function 2', 'Object 2', 200),
(6, 'Function 3', 'Object 2', 500);

CREATE TABLE access_rights ( 
  [id] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [user] varchar(50),
  [function] varchar(100),
  [object] varchar(100)
  );

INSERT INTO access_rights VALUES
(1, 'User', 'Function 1', ''),
(2, 'User', 'Function 2', 'Object 2');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE 
[records].[function] in 
(SELECT "function" FROM access_rights where "user"='User'  )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91496/7/0)**:

```
| ID |   FUNCTION |   OBJECT | SUM |
|----|------------|----------|-----|
|  1 | Function 1 | Object 1 | 900 |
|  2 | Function 2 | Object 1 | 600 |
|  4 | Function 1 | Object 2 | 750 |
|  5 | Function 2 | Object 2 | 200 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend reading Erland Sommarskog's "Dynamic Search Conditions" post [here](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

In your case, here's a fiddle with the pattern:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbcd8/13)

For posterity, here's the code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM records r
WHERE 
EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM access_rights a
  WHERE r.[function] = a.[function]
  and a.[user] = 'user'
  AND (A.[object] = r.[object] or a.[object] = ''))
```

Also, please stop using reserved words as column names.

Comment: I think you actually want to add the object filter to your subQ as well

Comment: Thanks. I actually didn't recognize that as a req.

Comment: You want it to be `AND (a.user = @user AND (A.object = r.object or a.object = ''))

Comment: He says null but I think the actual requirement is if no object is defined the user has access to all the objects for that function.

Comment: aw crap. i really should have read the actual question instead of assuming ... hang on

Answer (score 0):

You can separate this into two queries, then UNION the results together.

```
 SELECT *
   FROM records
  WHERE [function] IN
        (SELECT [function]
           FROM access_rights
          WHERE [object] = '')

UNION ALL

 SELECT R.*
   FROM records AS R
        INNER JOIN access_rights AS AR
                   ON AR.[function] = R.[function] AND AR.[object] = R.[object];
```